# How to alter a specific tag in css only if it contains a specific class

Tags: html, css

I want to alter the display of an 'a' tag in css when the tag contains the 'link' class. What i want to do is alter that element but only if it contains that class.

```
<a href="#" class="link"></a>  <--- Alter this one only 
<a href="#"></a>
<div class="link"></div>
```

I know there are many ways to do this, but i want CSS to verify that the element contains the class and then modify it.

Comment: You can do it with class selector as a.link {<your css here>}

Comment: @MohammadAslam post it as an actual answer with a short description about. YOur comment should actually solev the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can select it with the CSS selector `a.link`, which targets all anchor tags with the class `link`:

```css
a.link{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">1</a>
<a href="#">2</a>
<div class="link">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```css
a.link{text-decoration: none;}
```

```css
a.link{text-decoration: none; color: gray;}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">asdasdasda</a>
<a href="#">asdasdasd</a>
<div class="link">asdasd</div>
```

In this way, it will not affect the "link" CSS of the div class.